# Which is the correct technical name of those products, and a list of availables

Tags: air, appjs, node-webkit

I'm trying to find other type of products which allows me to create a desktop app through html5 + javascript. Actually I found these three but I still don't know their technical name so I really can't search for them on google. Any suggestion about this?

Also, I'm looking for a list of similar products, to choose the one that fits my needs.

I really like how you build interfaces with html + css + javascripts with great results, but I need quite good interaction with the O.S. to handle window. Expecially, I were looking for transparent windows which seems not implemented on node-webkit at the moment, while on AppJS seems ok but I don't like the idea of serving the content like a webserver, I prefer the node-webkit approach.

Comment: transparency work for node-webkit got some progress recently, please see https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/issues/132 for progress.

Comment: You can serve contents to appjs after window initialization manually. Appjs only uses a semi-server protocol for ease of use, it doesn't create a server at all. So there is no difference here with node-webkit.

Comment: Yea I tested now both node-webkit and app.js. I feel node-webkit more like an hack, but when writing the application and packaging it's far better than app.js (writing application on early stages). However, if I load javascript intensive apps from remote, like ExtJS, node-webkit becomes really slow, while AppJS feels responsive and load everything fast. Maybe the merged loops of chromium and node are creating some issues?

Comment: @Fire-Dragon-DoL There shouldn't be the performance impact you're seeing. And we haven't received bug reports like this so far. Would you please provide your code or open an issue in our github project?

Comment: I'll open an issue but you should understand that I didn't do deep research about it, just I found that the same code slows down a lot on node-webkit, while on appjs it works ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Search for "HTML5 Desktop" and you will find all the platforms that allows you to build desktop apps using html5 in the first page like appjs, tidesk, pokki, node-webkit etc.

Comment: Not perfect but it's working. I hoped for a *more focused* name